# non convex functions with no spurious local minima

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Are there functions for whom their local minima is also a global minima but the function itself is not convex?

Comment: $$f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$$ See also [quasiconvexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function).

Comment: Also pseudoconvexity. As an aside, $\sin$ fits the bill (but is not quasi- or pseudoconvex).